# How to emulate moving mirror without moving parts?

Tags: reflection, doppler-effect, casimir-effect

Is there any way to simulate moving mirror without moving parts? I read that they did it when they try to find [Dynamical Casimir effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect#Dynamical_Casimir_effect), but I did not get how it works. Or maybe there is another way how to achive this?

Basically I am looking for something like reflection of light (or radio waves) from relativistic mirror (with speed near speed of light or something like 50% of light speed) where I can see doppler effect and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Two common ways to do this come to mind: first, there's radar.   The velocity of a moving object can be determined by sending a microwave signal out (a chirp),
and beating the received (after reflection from a moving object) chirp
against a local reference.   In this way, a beat frequency is generated
that depends on the relative velocity of the moving object (the reflector).   A Hot Wheels radar gun aimed at  objects on a rotating
turntable can demonstrate this at home.  Or, you can speed on the highway
and the friendly police officer will tell you all about it at the hearing.

Secondly, there are gamma sources and absorbers so precise that a few millimeters per second of velocity makes a difference in the absorption that can be easily observed.  This happens because of the Mossbauer effect.   A Mossbauer spectrometer does include a moving (perhaps vibrating is a better word) part.

In neither case does a solid-state object create a moving target.  A Mossbauer spectrometer, though, scans a range of energies for absorption.  Absorption features
vary with solid-state changes in the absorber.   Those
can be induced by magnetization, temperature, pressure, even gravity, 
SO you can tweak the absorber and observe an absorption peak move to
a different doppler velocity.   It is possible to make a fixed-velocity
Mossbauer detector, and scan (with no moving parts) through the absorption
feature that it measures.

Comment: Mossbauer effect is very interesting. But can I achieve relativistic Doppler shift like this? I am more interested how that guys who detected Dynamical Casimir effect achieve relativistic speed of the mirror.

Comment: The precision of (for instance) 14.4 keV gamma from Fe_57 can be about one part in 10**12, and it's relativistic enough to be detectable at a millimeter per second (easily achievable in an audio speaker cone). Check out <http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Nuclear/mossfe.html>

Comment: Looks like I cannot explain it good.
If we have Doppler effect f=f0/(1-v/c) and I want to have v=c/2 for example. Let's say I have a electromagnetic wave with frequency f0 and if I have a mirror, which is moving with v=c/2 I will have f=f0/(1-c/(2c))=2*f0. Of course there should be relativistic Doppler effect, but let's add it later. As a result, I got double frequency. In reality, I cannot achieve speed of real mirror like c/2, because of strength of material, energy consumption etc. Guys who detected Dynamical Casimir effect claim they achieve it with some kind of simulation.

Comment: I was thinking that the difficulty in achieving c/2 speeds on a small scale was that an optical path must grow in length by many kilometers each microsecond.   So, I mentioned the Mossbauer effect which allows a trivial distance to yield a definite doppler effect (at much lower than c/2 speed).

Comment: Thanks. I got it. But how that guys did it who detected Dynamical Casimir effect? or they did some fake article :)